# What's the name of a special vertex coloring

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Who knows the name of the following coloring of graphs, a proper vertex coloring so that for every vertex its every two neighbors receive different colors?

Comment: Well from your original graph $G$ it's easy to make a new graph $G'$ with the same vertex set which has $u$ and $v$ adjacent iff they are at distance $<= 2$ from each other, and then you're just looking at usual colorings of $G'$, right?

Comment: Also known as an L(1,1) labelling….

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a graph $G$, the *$t$-th power* of $G$ is the graph $G^t$ with the same vertex set as $G$ and where two vertices are adjacent in $G^t$ if they are connected by a path with at most $t$ edges in $G$.  The *distance-$t$ chromatic number* of $G$, often denoted $\chi_t(G)$, is the chromatic number of $G^t$. As noted by Sam Hopkins in the comments, you are asking about $\chi_2(G)$. So, your colouring is known as a *distance-$2$ colouring* of $G$.  See this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07639) of Kang and Pirot, where this terminology and notation is used.

Comment: In addition, some people call it a 2-distance $k$-colouring, which seems odd to me.